# Why do we use normal solution to system of linear equations instead of $A^{-1}b$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we have $Ax=b$, why can't we just solve for $x$ using $A^{-1}b$, and instead go through the trouble of doing $A^TAx=A^Tb\implies x=(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$?

Comment: Because it might not be the case that $A$ is a square matrix (i.e., not invertible in some cases). You might at least guess what's the nature of $A^{\intercal}A$.

Comment: $(A^TA)^{-1}A^T$ is also known as pseudo-inverse of $A$. There are cases such as $A$ might neither be invertible nor square matrix. If $A$ is square matrix and singular, then $A^TA$ will be also singular, so I don't see the point of using pseudo-inverse. In the $A$ is $m\times n$ case, $A^TA$ is symmetric square matrix and can have inverse, so you can find unique solution to the given system.

Comment: The solution $(A^TA)^{-1}A^Tb$ is more generally useful for finding $x$ to minimize $||Ax-b||$, including cases when there is no $x$ that solves $Ax=b$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're asking about this problem in the context of least squares regression.

It's because inverses only exist for square matrices. In the case of least squares regression, we obtain the equation $X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = \mathbf{y}$, in which, generally speaking, $X$ is an $n \times p$ matrix, $\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} \in \mathbb{R}^p$, and $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$. Generally, $n$ is considered to be larger than $p$, so $X^T$ is a $p \times n$ matrix that cannot be inverted because it is not a square matrix.

However, taking the equation $X\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = \mathbf{y}$, multiplying $X^T$ on the left sides, we obtain
$$X^TX\hat{\boldsymbol\beta} = X^T\mathbf{y}$$
in which case, $X^TX$ is a $p \times p$ matrix that *can* be inverted, assuming $X$ has full-column rank.

Comment: I'm  not sure why you switched notation from $Ax=b$ to $X \hat{\beta} = y$ (which seems more intimidating).

Comment: @Michael The notation I use is standard for least squares regression.

Answer (score 0):

In least squares regression $Ax=b$ is typically over-determined and there is no consistent solution. You simply cannot say $x = A^{-1}b$.

Just to note, the $x$ in $A^T Ax = A^T b$ is not the $x$ in $Ax=b$. As said, there typically is no x for which $Ax = b$. You can think of $Ax$ as a sum of the columns of A (each column of A is multiplied by an $x_j$). What you then look for is the combination of the columns of $A$ which is nearest to $b$. If $A\hat{x}$ is that combination then $A\hat{x} - b$ will be orthogonal to every column of $A$. We can capture that orthogonality with $A^T (A\hat{x} - b) = 0$